# Haproxy Connect with client with public ssl cert and Connect to server with insecure ssl

Tags: haproxy

My senario is most likely [SSL/TLS bridging or re-encryption](https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/deployment_guides/tls_layouts.html#ssl-tls-bridging-or-re-encryption) but my backend server has a private cert that i dont have access to. So Haproxy needs to connect to the backend with insecure mode. How can i achive this configurations?

Answer (score 2):

Solved using

```
frontend icinga
   bind *:5665 ssl no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 crt /etc/ssl/private/haproxy/haproxy-com.pem
   mode tcp
   default_backend sss

backend sss
    mode tcp
    server name url:port ssl verify none
```